# Python taking int from list?

Tags: python

So i'm trying to implement a turing Machine. I currently have a list of following:

```
[ B, Number1, +, Number2, +, Number3, B]
```

So i want to add two numbers from list but when i try to add as following:

```
def turingMachine(list, number2):
    temp = list[1]
    temp2 = list[number2]
    sum = temp + temp2
    list[1] = temp + temp2
    list[number2] = 0
```

It returns numbers added as string. Since the list consists of multiple data types, how do i convert the string to int and then add it?

Comment: Do you just want convert an int to str? Sorry I am sure what you mean.

Comment: Simply `int('2')`?

Comment: Your list is not a valid python object. Are they all `str`s?

Comment: @Chris yes they are all strings

Comment: @SeakyLone Yes Exactly

Comment: Someone has answered below. To convert basic types, you can usually do `int(str), str(int), list(str)`

Comment: How does it relate to the Turing Machine?

Comment: @youkaichao there is more to this code. This is just a small function part of the turing machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert them with int()

```
def turingMachine(list, number2):
    temp = int(list[1])
    temp2 = int(list[number2])
    sum = temp + temp2
    list[1] = temp + temp2
    list[number2] = 0
```

that function may throw an exception, so you have to use `try/except` when you use it or change it a little bit:

ls = [1,"a",3,4,5]

```
def turingMachine(list, number2):
  temp = list[1]
  temp2 = list[number2]
  try:
    temp = int(temp)
    temp2 = int(temp2)
    sum_ = temp + temp2
    list[1] = sum_
    list[number2] = 0
  except:
    print("error: cannot convert " + str(temp) + " or " + str(temp2) + " to int")
```

Comment: I think a try/except is needed as well, in case any element is not a number.

Comment: @FatihAkici yes that's accurate